# xElement remove parent node

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have an XDocument that I wish to remove the entire Allocation node when the Account node value = TEST

```
<Order>
  <Quantity>800</Quantity>
  <Allocations>
    <Allocation>
       <Account>ACCT1</Account>
       <Quantity>100</Quantity>
    </Allocation>
    <Allocation>
      <Account>TEST</Account>
      <Quantity>300</Quantity>  
    </Allocation>
   <Allocation>
      <Account>ACCT4</Account>
      <Quantity>400</Quantity>
   </Allocation>
 </<Allocations>
</Order>

And my code:

XElement root = XElement.Parse(util.DocAsString(xmlDoc));
IEnumerable<string> acctList = from acct in root.Descendants("Account")
                                            select (string)acct;
foreach (var acct in acctList)
 {
    root.Elements("Allocation").Where(aa => aa.Element("Account").Value == "TEST").Remove();
}
```

However, this in not removing the node.  Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the expression inside your `foreach` loop doesn't remove anything because the part before `Remove()` doesn't return any element. And that was because `<Allocation>` is not direct child of the root element (you can use `Descendants()` instead of `Elements()` to fix that).

Ultimately, you don't even need that `foreach` loop at all :

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(util.DocAsString(xmlDoc));

root.Descendants("Allocation")  
    .Where(aa => aa.Element("Account").Value == "TEST")
    .Remove();
```

To preserve changes back to the XML file (if you actually read them from file), don't forget to save the modified `XElement` back to the original file.